# iOS UIPanGestureRecognizer prevents scroll

Tags: ios, uigesturerecognizer

I am overriding my horizontal image UIScrollView with a panning gesture recognizer to detect a user swipe.

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer *panGesture = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGestureCaptured)];
[imgHorizontalScrollView addGestureRecognizer:panGesture];
```

My question is: Is there a way for me to reset imgHorizontalScrollView's pan gesture recognizer back to default in the panGestureCaptured method?  The reason I ask is because since I am overriding this gesture, once the user swipes and the gesture is picked up, I am no longer able to scroll in the scroll view.  I also tried to remove the gesture but that also prevents me from being able to scroll.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

try `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` with scrollView's gestureRecognizer got by `panGestureRecognizer`

Comment: May I add; You need to set your view controller as the delegate for the `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and obviously, set the return value of `gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:` to `YES` :]

Comment: When returning `YES` you'll still get the ugly result of your cells subview (if your using it for dragging) panning together with the `tableView` scrolling. I'd like to see if the `tableView` has direction locked and then stop the recognizer if not so (ignoring vertical scrolling)

Comment: Oh... Just achieved it using  `- (BOOL)gestureRecognizerShouldBegin:(UIGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer` and only returning `YES` if scrolling horizontally.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting

```
panGesture.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
```

If that doesn't work, you should find a way to change your gesture handler to the `scrollViewDidScroll:` delegate method

Comment: unfortunately it has no effect